# UILabel Text Not Appearing on Some Devices for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

This problem appears to only affect the iPad Mini 5 and the iPad Mini 4. **Not the iPhone 11**.
It's only the UILabel fields text. It's only on the Device, not on the Simulator.

The text display fine on anything but the iPad Mini 5 device nor the iPad Mini 4.
I've tried changing the fonts. I've tried changing just about everything that's changeable.
The app itself has been on the app store and working fine for years. Now it's not working on the iPad.
I've tried checking the uppercase/lowercase thing mentioned elsewhere. The UILabel Field background shows clearly. Just not the text that's supposed to appear in the fields.
Thanks
Attached is an image of the iPad Storyboard. The [Change Image] icon is a Button, and displays and works fine.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide piece of code / storyboard / xib with the described view so we can reproduce this and point to the possible issues?

Comment: Are you working with localization ?

Comment: No. No Localisation

Comment: “It's only the UIText fields text.” This appears to be a label, not a text field.

Comment: @HarryMcGovern did you ever find the solution? I'm running into the same issue...

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Any chance your device is on Dark Mode? If so, that would explain why text doesn't show and background does. Dark Mode by default will switch black texts to white and the other way around.

If that's the case and you don't want to support dark mode on you app, just disable it by adding this to your `.plist`:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Comment: Interesting addition. It happened on iPads not in dark mode, but it’s a good one to check.

Comment: @HarryMcGovern - thanks for his, now I don't need to pull the remaining 3 strands of hair remaining !

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. 
In the Attribute Inspector of the *UIText* I mean UILabel fields not displaying on the iPad, change the Behaviour from Enabled to Not Enabled. 
In other words, I had that box ticked. I unticked it, and now it works on all devices.
Thanks for the responses.

Comment: That shouldn’t make any difference.

Comment: It does though. I went back and ticked the box - text disappears on the iPad.